# Object promise issue in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to extract the data from a .json file and display them on the web browser (with HTML). When I do that, the web browser display [Object promise] instead of the element that I'm trying to display.

Here is my JS code:

```
async function getName(){

    var api = "name.json";

    let response = await fetch("name.json");
    let data = await response.json();
    
    console.log(data["people"][index]["name"]);
    
    var ourName = JSON.stringify(data["people"][index]["name"]);
    return ourName;
}
```

Comment: Looks like promise is pending. Are you getting this printed in console `console.log(data["people"][index]["name"]);`. Also can you check `console.log(data)`?

Comment: A `async function` will always return a Promise! So wherever you're writing the value to the DOM, it has to be either `node.textContent = await getName()` or `getName().then(name => node.textContent = name);`

Comment: *"...and display them on the web browser (with HTML)"*: there is no code in your question that does that.